# Odoo: Conditional invisible attribute on fields only works in one direction?

Tags: xml, inheritance, odoo, odoo-view

I'm trying to make a field invisible on condition in an Odoo form view.
When "Can be sold" is checked ==> "Product Manager" should be invisible:

[image]

[image]

I tried using the attribute "invisible" with a domain in the inherited view of the products form:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="product_template_form_inherit">
    <field name="name">product.template.product.form</field>
    <field name="model">product.template</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_only_form_view" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="product_manager"  position="attributes">
                    <attribute name="invisible">[('sale_ok', '=', True)]</attribute>
        </field>    
</field>
</record>
```

When the field sale_ok is true, the product_manager field is actually hidden. But **when field sale_ok becomes false again**, the **field product_manager stays hidden**.

I also tried this instead:

```
<field name="product_manager" attrs="{'invisible': [('sale_ok', '=', True)]}"/>
```

This doesn't work either.

I've also tried other domains like:

```
[('sale_ok', '==', True)]
[('sale_ok', '!=', False)]
[('sale_ok', '=', 'True')]
```

Not really sure what's wrong here... How to make it (in)visible when (un)checked?

What I'm eventually after is the following thing:
When a checkbox is checked, the form should change immediately without saving. Fields have to be added and removed. Is that possible?

**Edit:**

I can hide/unhide product manager now with ChesuCR's answer.
However when I try the same thing with "loc_rack" (Storage Location==>Rack) it gives error:

```
Field(s) `arch` failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition

Error details:
Element '<field name="loc_rack">' cannot be located in parent view
```

This is the code I used:

```
<field name="loc_rack"  position="replace">
    <field name="loc_rack" attrs="{'invisible': [('sale_ok', '=', True)]}"/>
</field>
```

Why can't I do the same with this field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works well to me

```
<record id="custom_product_template_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">custom.product.template.form</field>
    <field name="model">product.template</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_form_view" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="product_manager"  position="replace">
            <field name="product_manager" attrs="{'invisible': [('sale_ok', '=', True)]}"/>
        </field>
    </field>  
</record>
```

If you find any problems you can try the "federico" answer just to modify the `attrs` attribute. My solution may modify or remove other attributes if they already exist in the original form.

Comment: Works perfect! Fault was in the position="attribute". Should have been "replace" like you.

Comment: One more question. This works for product_manager, but when I try this with loc_rack, it doesn't work? I've edited my OP.

Comment: Make sure you are inheriting the correct view. What do you have in the `inherit_id` field?

Comment: `loc_rack` is in the `stock.view_template_property_form` view

Answer (score 6):

Using `position="replace"` could bring problems, the best option is to use `position="attributes"`

Imagine that another installed module (named module X) is inheriting the tag you are replacing. When you update your Odoo system, it will crash because the module X cannot find the tag you replaced.

This code works perfectly for me:

```
<field name="product_manager"  position="attributes">
    <attribute name="attrs">{'invisible': [('sale_ok', '=', True)]}</attribute>
</field>
```